# One of listeners must count and slice given target + knppaginator symfony2 bundle

Tags: php, symfony, pagination, knppaginator

I'm trying to use the KnpPaginatorBundle for Symfony2 that you can find [here](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle).

When I try to do the following:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$query = $em->getRepository('VolleyScoutBundle:Users')->findAll();

$paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
$pagination = $paginator->paginate(
    $query,
    $this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1)/*page number*/,
    10/*limit per page*/
);


// parameters to template
return $this->render('VolleyScoutBundle:Admin:accounts.html.twig', array('pagination' => $pagination));
```

I always get an error like this: `One of listeners must count and slice given target`. When I dump the query before the pagination I just get an array with Entity objects from user..

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should pass a Query, not a result set into the paginator.

Comment: The KnpPaginator can paginate `ArrayCollection` and `array` objects aswell @Uriziel - have a look at the **[documenation](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle#controller)**. @nielsv please include the exception and stacktrace in your question. The exception originates from the method `Paginator::paginate(...)` in `knplabs/knp-components` **[here](https://github.com/KnpLabs/knp-components/blob/master/src/Knp/Component/Pager/Paginator.php#L110)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting the same error.

It didn't seem to be working for me unless I used the LTS version of Symfony2:

```
"symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
```

However I also used an EventListener which might have helped:

https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/custom_pagination_subscribers.md